# How to get <select> value to update before printing?

Tags: javascript

I found an odd thing when printing  values.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#print_btn').on('click', function(){

    var divToPrint=document.getElementById("print_tbl");
    newWin= window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
});
});
```

[Take a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3hk5hon/1/)

If you click Print, you will see the value is 1.
If you change the value to 2, then hit Print again, the value is still 1.

How can I get the print image to reflect the change?

Comment: The problem is you're only pushing the HTML over to the print window. Unfortunately, the `<select>` element stores its selectedIndex internally and doesn't update the html when this changes. One way would be to construct some html that represent a list that does have a specific item selected, namely - the correct option has the `selected` attribute. You could step through the options 1 by 1, outputting their outerHTML if it isn't selected and some slightly different html if it is. The `.selectedIndex` member of the `<select>` element can tell you which it is in a single-selection list.

Comment: CSS print Media, there is no need to open a window and set the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While epascarello's comment is the best way to do it, you can side-step this approach by just adding the `selected` attribute to the option that corresponds to its parent's `selectedIndex` member. Once done, the correct option will be shown in the printed result.

Here's some JS that will do the trick:

```
function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}
function allByTag(tagName,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementsByTagName(tagName);}

function forEachNode(nodeList, func){for (var i=0, n=nodeList.length; i<n; i++) func(nodeList[i], i, nodeList); }
// **** below function updated in an EDIT ****
function setListSelectedAttrib(selectElem)
{
    var selectedIndex = selectElem.selectedIndex;
    var i, n = selectElem.options.length;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
         if (i == selectedIndex)
             selectElem.options[i].setAttribute('selected', '');
        else
             selectElem.options[i].removeAttribute('selected');
    }
}


function onPrintClicked(evt)
{
    var elemToPrint = byId('print_tbl');
    var selectElems = allByTag('select', elemToPrint);

    forEachNode(selectElems, eachSelElemFunc);
    function eachSelElemFunc(curElem, indexOfCurElem, listOfElems)
    {
        setListSelectedAttrib(curElem);
    }

    var newWin = window.open();
    newWin.document.write(elemToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close(); 
}
```

See here for a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jpkz0fyp/1/

Comment: Thanks for the code. it's almost works. It appears it is leaving SELECTED tags behind when it adds them to new OPTIONs. So it only allows you to change the SELECT once.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss - simple to fix. In the setListSelectedAttrib function, just step through the option elements one by one. If it's the selected one, do what I'm already doing. If it isn't, call .removeAtribute('selected'). I've updated my solution and the fiddle link. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt to use css media queries instead of javascript to determine what is printed. You can get started by using the following code

```
@media print {
    * {
        visibility : hidden;
    }
    .print {
        visibility : visible;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k2mtaob2/2/

Notice in the provided example only **World** will be printed in the fiddle